# Why does devenv.exe occasionally not respect /Edit flag and launch a new instance?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I am trying to automatically load an extra file into a current instance of Visual Studio 2015 by invoking devenv.exe /Edit , and it usually works, except for sometimes it would fail to detect a running instance (as it is supposed to according to [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xee0c8y7.aspx)) and launch a new one (sometimes even a different version e.g. 2010 instead of 2015) Why could this be happening? Is this a bug and/or is there a workaround for this?